# Python-CSV write column(s) at given indices to new file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the column(s) in a csv file where a word is present. the example shown here is for "car".

NOTE: CANNOT USE PANDAS

here is the sample in_file:

```
12,life,car,good,exellent
10,gift,truck,great,great
11,time,car,great,perfect
```

the desired output for out_file is:

```
car
truck
car
```

This is the current code:

```
def project_columns(in_file, out_file, indices):
    #indices[0] = 2
    col = indices[0]
    with open(in_file) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        
        with open(out_file, 'w') as out:
            w = csv.writer(out)
            for row in reader:
                w.writerow(row[col])
```

the variable indices contains the indices of the column. for "car" indices = [2,2].

out_file currently contains:

```
c,a,r
t,r,u,c,k
c,a,r
```

How should I fix this to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat car.csv                                                                                                                                                                
12,life,car,good,exellent
10,gift,truck,great,great
11,time,car,great,perfect

import csv

with open('car.csv') as car_file:
    r = csv.reader(car_file)
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        w = csv.writer(out_file)
        for row in r:
            w.writerow([row[2]])

cat out.csv                                                                                                                                                               
car
truck
car
```

Comment: this works but the outfile.txt is wrong. row1: c,a,r | row2: t,r,u,c,k | c,a,r

Comment: Did you do `w.writerow(row[2])` instead of  `w.writerow([row[2]])`? Note the extra square brackets.

Comment: yes I did, it still prints each letter with a comma in between.

Comment: Add to your question the code you are running.

Comment: I have added to the question to reflect the current problem.

Comment: Which is as I said above you did `w.writerow(row[col])` instead of `w.writerow([row[col]])`. Attention to detail is a big part of programming.